# Unity - Problems with script to drag object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am using the c# code below to drag a game object within a specific rectangular area. This works fine but the problem I have is that my object moves too fast and to slow it down I have tried using a speed variable. It limits the speed in the x direction correctly but for some reason it completely stops the object from moving in the Y direction. This happens even when I am only attempting to slow down the X direction as a test. My aim is to slow down the speed in both direction within the area.

Please advise what I am doing wrong here and any improvements I can make.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class drag : MonoBehaviour {

public float maxXValue = 9f;

Vector3 dist;
float posX;
float posY;
float speedX = 0.3f;
float speedY = 0.3f;

void OnMouseDown(){
    dist = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    posX = Input.mousePosition.x - dist.x;
    posY = Input.mousePosition.y - dist.y;
}

void OnMouseDrag(){

    Vector3 curPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x - posX, Input.mousePosition.y - posY, dist.z);  
    Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curPos);

    if (GameManager.instance.gameStart == false) {
        worldPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (worldPos.x, -5f, 5f);
        worldPos.y = Mathf.Clamp (worldPos.y, -13f, -13f);
    } else {
        worldPos.x = Mathf.Clamp (worldPos.x * speedX, -maxXValue, maxXValue);//Even when just limiting the X
        worldPos.y = Mathf.Clamp (worldPos.y, -17.2f, -13f);                  //value the object no longer  
    }                                                                         //moves in the Y direction        

    transform.position = worldPos;
}
}
```

Comment: You've hardcoded your values so of course they will never change: worldPos.y = Mathf.Clamp (worldPos.y, -17.2f, -13f);

Comment: I think the base problem is that your object stops dragging when it moves too fast because the mouse ends up no longer over it, and that triggers an `OnMouseExit` and that breaks the "drag"-ness.  If you want it to follow the mouse even beyond that, you need to use `Update()` instead.